# Altium PCB messy Components Placement

Tags: components, altium, replacement

I have a problem with PCB.  When I click **Design -> Update PCB Document** my components are passed to PCB in a messy way. I couldn't solve this problem. Is there any way to solve this?

[image: Messy Components]

[image: Messy_2]

Comment: What do you mean by "messy" what is your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem.
I deleted the pages which are problem.
Then I add this pages one by one. And the problem have solved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've moved them around. If they are being placed wildly out of the center of the area, check that the origin on your footprints is correct. Usually you want pin 1, the center of the part, or some mechanical position **on the part** that makes sense such as centered where a connector should sit on the edge of the PCB.

You can put the origin wherever you like on a footprint, including 100mm away from the pads.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Actually, I couldn't move any part. this messy placement occured automatically. All of my components origins are at the center. When I change origin to pin 1 and reupdate PCB Doc., there is no change. The rooms and components still messy.

Comment: You should work with version control to keep your different versions. Try right click on your project > local history maybe you will find your previous PCB placement

Comment: Once they've been placed, updates do not move the placement. You can delete the ones (on the PCB) that are not placed and update from the schematic again and the deleted parts should re-appear distributed more-or-less neatly in rows. If you can't move the parts on the PCB there are a few possibilities- selection filter, parts too far negative locations, or even some licensing issues.

Comment: I checked everything in my PCB library nad schematic library. The origins of the all of parts are center. When I click to Update PCB Document, my components passed to PCB  room by room. But some components are out of the rooms. Some rooms are so big. And the most important problem is **components are scattered around.** I couldn't solve yet.